# Can I cache my transactions to Redis ,update to blockchain later?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Hey I m building a platform for web3,  I wanna save my user's gas fee.

I m thinking cache all the transactions into Redis .. then update to the blockchain once a day!  so I only cost gas fee once..

I don't know, its a good way to approach?  or it's a stupid idea?

my point is, My customer doesn't really know (or) care their balance updated on chain.. why don't we just cache it and update it later..

Answer (score 0):

Updating the blockchain is not only updating balances; it's the moment in time when correctness is verified as well - to be more specific when a transaction is added to blockchain it is guaranteed that balances are correct, e.g. there is no double spending.

If you cache transactions outside of blockchain, then you take a risk of double spending. Between time a transaction is "cached" and time when it is committed to blockchain the customer may already spend all tokens.

The question is about the business - if a customer will decide to double spend - is it a real problem from business point of view? For example, if every transaction is just few cents, then it may be an ok risk to take.